# How to force a functional component to rerender on submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, state

I have form inputs that update their form state(X) with an `onChange` then i have a form `onSubmit` submit that has to do 2 things:

1. update a separate state(Y) using info from state(X)
2. run an actual function that would use state(Y)

```js
const [ethValue, setEthValue] = React.useState({ethValue: 0});

const submit = (e) => {
    setEthValue(() => { return { ethValue: formData.value } })
    e.preventDefault();
    runContractFunction()
};
```

It is working, however in order for it to complete the task I have to press **Submit** button twice, due to asynchronous nature of set functions.
In order for it to finish setting i decided to use re-rendering so it would finish setting the state, but neither of methods i tried, work.

Since I use functional components i cannot use `forceUpdate()` and i cannot put `useEffect` inside of my `submit` function because it would put the `useEffect` hook outside of the component function body.

I want to make it so you have to press **Submit** once and not twice for it to work.
How do I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Pass that 'Y' value to the function as argument which uses it as state.

```js
const submit = (e) => {
    setEthValue(() => { return { ethValue: formData.value } })
    e.preventDefault();
    runContractFunction({
      ethValue: formData.value
    })
};
```

Comment: Sadly its not an option in my case - i tried that in the very beginning and it is not possible due to the design of the API i'm using without a lengthy workaround

Comment: try adding ethValue as dependency in useEffect from where you are calling that function